# Sed to replace modify large html list of links

Tags: sed

What I've got:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="https://example.com.com/link-1"></li>
<li><a href="https://example.com.com/link-2"></li>
<li><a href="https://example.com.com/link-3" ></li>
<!-- many more items here --> 
</ul>
```

Desired end result:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="link-1.html"></li>
<li><a href="link-2.html"></li>
<li><a href="link-3.html" ></li>
<!-- many more items here --> 
</ul>
```

Currently I've come up with something like:

```
sed 's/https:\/\/example.com.com//g' test.txt | sed 's/" *>/.html">/g'
```

But this is clearly (a) inefficient and (b) won't work inline (i.e. `sed -i` when used in conjunction with `find`, for example)

What would a better approach for this be ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a capturing group to avoid the second `sed` invocation like this :

```
sed -e 's%https://[^"]*/\([^"]*\)%\1.html%'
```

The `%` separator saves the need for escaping forward slashes.

##### *Edit*

If you want to make sure the substitution only occurs for instances of `https://example.com` inside lines starting with `<li><a ...>` tags, you could try:

```
sed -e '/^<li><a /s%"https://example.com[^"]*/\([^"]*\)%"\1.html%'
```

Based on the data sample you provided, you should get :

```
<ul>
<li><a href="link-1.html"></li>
<li><a href="link-2.html"></li>
<li><a href="link-3.html" ></li>
<!-- many more items here --> 
</ul>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: That looks great, thanks.  Only thing I guess is checking for "example.com" might be a good idea because there could be other links to other sites in the same html which should not be changed.